# Why is equiaxed titanium better suited for HT application than columnar

Tags: materials

My guess is that the grains are already in a thermodynamically-stable spherical shape and thus don't grow as fast as in columnar structures and leave big areas without Ti<sub>3</sub>Al precipitation to hinder dislocations

Note: English is not my first language with equiaxed I mean "globular", maybe that helps

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by High temperature. For refinery equipment Titanium at HT is an oxymoron- not used . For compressor section of gas turbines with warm temperatures Ti is good. It is creep range where columnar gains improve strength. I never used Ti in creep temperatures so it seems normal for me to used equi-axed material. Also , for higher temperatures, likely alloys are used and can be two phase which changes the situation. Because we used Ti for corrosion resistance , we used "pure" Ti. In my limited experience ; Columnar grain is a cast product ,not produced by forging.